# Invalid directory for Ruby Development Kit

Tags: ruby, installation

I'm trying to install the Ruby Development Kit from http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads but I run into some problems at the command prompt.

After running `C:\Ruby\DevKit>ruby dk.rb init` I got the following success response:

> [INFO] found RubyInstaller v2.0.0 at C:/Ruby/Ruby200-x64
>
> Initialization complete! Please review and modify the auto-generated 'config.yml' file to ensure it contains the root directories to all of the installed Rubies when you run 'ruby dk.rb install'.

Then I ran `C:\Ruby\DevKit>ruby dk.rb review` and got this success response:

> Based upon the settngs in the 'config.yml' file generated from running 'ruby dk.rb init' and any of your customizations, DevKit functionality will be injected into the following Rubies when you run 'ruby dk.rb install'.
>
> C:/Ruby/Ruby200-x64

Finally, I ran the `C:\DevKit>ruby dk.rb install` line, as it seems everything was working fine up until this point. Unfortunately, I keep getting this message:

> [ERROR] Skipping invalid directory 'C:/Ruby/Ruby200-x64'

I don't know what to do! Thanks kindly for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error. As mentioned by TSG, config.yml had wrong path for ruby. For example, mine installed it to c:\Ruby200x64 but the config.yml had it as c:\Ruby200-x64 .
config.yml takes it from path variables of windows. If you use windows, I suggest you to update your path environment variables as well.. both user variables and system variables..

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you changed the name of your Ruby directory from *Ruby200-x64* to *Ruby*.  In your DevKit folder, open the file "config.yml" and change the last line to reflect the proper folder name of your Ruby install.